# Can Angular's HttpRequest objects be saved in local storage?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-http

In my Angular/Ionic app I want to save HttpRequest objects to local storage (using Ionic's Native storage), called from http interceptor under some specific conditions:

```
public addRequestToQueue(request) {
    let queuedRequests = [];
    this.storage.get('queuedRequests').then((requests) => {
      if(requests) {
        queuedRequests = requests;
      }
      queuedRequests.push(request);
      this.storage.set('queuedRequests', queuedRequests);
    });
  }
```

But I get errors in console:

```
    Uncaught (in promise): DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': function () {
                _this.headers = new Map();
                Object.keys(headers).forEach(function ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
Error: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': function () {
                _this.headers = new Map();
                Object.keys(headers).forEach(function ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
```

How can I save them in localstorage for later use? Is it possible? Maybe some method of serialization should be used?

Comment: I must will asking me first if this is necessary because I can make a request when I need it.

Comment: @Antoniodelamata in case when device is offline, we want to modify request and re-send it later automatically.

Comment: service worker would be better suited for this task. look at workbox (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/)

Answer (score -1):

**Update**
After researching a bit about this error I found out that usually there is a framework or tool adding properties to the Array prototype, which makes it unable to copy the `keys`. You can reference the following [github discussion](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/2158) on pouchdb, where users had a similar error.

Just to verify that nothing else is interfering with your storage, try to encode the request and drop it in:

```
public addRequestToQueue(request) {
  this.storage.set('request', JSON.stringify(request));
});
```

This

Comment: I am not using localstorage, as I said I am using ionic's storage:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/